# Questions about logic homework/proofs - what should a good answer look like?

Tags: discussion

Apologies if something like this has been asked before, but after searching around a bit I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

When someone asks a question about logic proof exercises, and they don't show any effort in trying to solve the exercise themselves, we probably shouldn't answer their question. That much is clear. But what about if they *do* show some effort like, for example, an attempt at a solution. A few hours ago I answered [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/61427/formal-proof-errors/61432#61432), because the user tried to solve it unsuccessfully. Clearly they showed some effort, but still, how should we answer their question? I wasn't sure if the way I answered it was appropriate for the purpose of philosophy SE though...

Is an answer like mine, that includes the entire proof ever appropriate? If so, when? Is it enough that the asker showed some effort at an attempted solution for us post an entire solution? If not, then does this mean answers to questions about logic exercises should always be hints or suggestions only, and never a complete solution?

Comment: Great question, I have wondered about this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I liked your answer: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/61432/29944

The OP used a different proof checker. What you provided was a hint on how the OP might proceed with their proof checker. So, it wasn't a complete answer to the OP's problem, but it demonstrated that the answer approached in the way you provided was correct.

I would have also given a link to Magnus, et al, *forall x: Calgary Remix*: http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/ This would be a way for them to get more information on the terminology used in your answer although they can get there from the link to the proof checker.

Comment: Thanks. I actually didn't even notice that they had a free book too, even though it's right in the first paragraph on the site... BTW, it was because of one of your answers that I even found out about the really neat web proof checker at https://proofs.openlogicproject.org :)